# UTF-8 bit representation

Tags: utf-8

I'm learning about UTF-8 standards and this is what I'm learning :

```
Definition and bytes used
UTF-8 binary representation         Meaning
0xxxxxxx                            1 byte for 1 to 7 bits chars
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx                   2 bytes for 8 to 11 bits chars
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx          3 bytes for 12 to 16 bits chars
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 4 bytes for 17 to 21 bits chars
```

And I'm wondering, why 2 bytes UTF-8 code is not `10xxxxxx` instead, thus gaining 1 bit all the way up to 22 bits with a 4 bytes UTF-8 code? The way it is right now, 64 possible values are lost (from `1000000` to `10111111`). I'm not trying to argue the standards, but I'm wondering why this is so?

** **EDIT** **

Even, why isn't it

```
UTF-8 binary representation         Meaning
0xxxxxxx                            1 byte for 1 to 7 bits chars
110xxxxx xxxxxxxx                   2 bytes for 8 to 13 bits chars
1110xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx          3 bytes for 14 to 20 bits chars
11110xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 4 bytes for 21 to 27 bits chars
```

...?

Thanks!

Comment: If you drop `10xxxxxx` you can use `10xxxxxx xxxxxxxx` 2 bytes for 8 - 14 bits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UTF-8 is self-synchronising.  Something examining the bytes can tell if it's at the start of a UTF-8 character, or part-way through one.

Let's say you have two characters in your scheme: `10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`

If the parser picks up at the second octet, it can't tell that it's not to read the second and third octets as one character.  With UTF-8, the parser can tell that it's in the middle of a character and continue ahead to the start of the next one, while emitting some state to mention the corrupted symbol.

For the edit: if the top bit is clear, UTF-8 parsers *know* that they're looking at a character represented in one octet.  If it is set, it's a multi-octet character.

It's all about error recovery and easy classification of octets.

Comment: This synchronization allows also traversing chars in UTF-8 strings backwards.